# silex project:the requested url not found

Tags: php, controller, routes, silex

i have an issue of a project build by silex, i'm newbie in this framework.
only the url that point to my index page is working , all other routes are not found.

here is the code how i get my routes in my application

```
$app['routes'] = $app->extend(
  'routes', 
  function (RouteCollection $routes, Application $app) {
    $loader = new YamlFileLoader(new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/config'));
    $collection = $loader->load('routes.yml');
    $routes->addCollection($collection);

    return $routes;
  }
);
```

all routes are well present in this file: config/routes.yml.

my application is steps of forms, step1 wich is my index page is working fine, but when i click on continue, i got  the url not found : here is the form

```
 <div class="formulaire">
    <div class="container">
        {{ form_start(form, {'action': path('step2'), 'method': 'POST'}) }}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                {{ form_label(form.title) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"> 
                {{ form_widget(form.title) }}
                <br/><br/><br/>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                {{ form_label(form.lastname) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.lastname) }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                {{ form_label(form.firstname) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.firstname) }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                {{ form_label(form.email.first) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.email.first) }}
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                {{ form_label(form.email.second) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.email.second) }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                {{ form_label(form.mobile) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.mobile) }}
                <span class="placeholder">Merci d'indiquer votre numéro précédé de l'indicatif pays (exemple: 0033491588853)<br />
                Please indicate your country code before your phone number (example : 0033491588853)</span>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="obligation"><br />* champs obligatoires</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-sm-offset-9 col-md-offset-9">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit">continuer</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

here the route:

```
step2:
 path: /professional-informations
 defaults: { _controller: 'Tour\Controller\StepController::step2Action'}
```

here is the controller:

```
   /**
    * "Your professional informations" Action

    * 
    * Template : 
    *  -   pages/steps/step2.html.twig
    * 
    * URI : 
    *  -   /professional-informations
    * 
    * Route name :  
    *  -   step2
    * 
    * @param Request     $request
    * @param Application $app
    * 
    * @return Response
    */
    public function step2Action(Request $request, Application $app)
    {

      $emailsSTEP1 = $request->request->all();
      $email = $emailsSTEP1["step1"]["email"]["first"];
    $data = DataWeb::getRecord($email);

    if (isset($data)) {            
        $email = urldecode($email);
        $data = DataWeb::getRecord($email);
        $user = new Client();
        $user->setEmail($email);

        if ($data['Token'] === null) {
            $user->generateConfirmToken();
            $token = $user->getConfirmToken();
            DataWeb::requalif($email, $token);

            return $app['twig']->render('pages/requalif.html.twig', array(
                        'email' => $email,
                        'token' => $token
            ));
        }

        $user->initFormApi($data);
        $app['session']->set('user', serialize($user));

        list ($step, $form) = $this->processForm($request, $app, 2);
        return $app['twig']->render('pages/steps/step' . $step . '.html.twig', array(
                       'step' => $step,
                       'form' => $form->createView()
        ));


    } else {
         list ($step, $form) = $this->processForm($request, $app, 2);
         return $app['twig']->render('pages/steps/step' . $step . '.html.twig', array(
                        'step' => $step,
                        'form' => $form->createView()
         ));
    }


}
```

I will appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems your routes are not binded to its name. Have you checked the HTML source code of the step1 form? Where does the *action* parameter points to?

Comment: @mTorres I mentioned above that the action is to the next form  {{ form_start(form, {'action': path('step2'), 'method': 'POST'}) }}

Comment: Yes, but I meant that you take a look at the HTML translated from this code and check which path does it yeld the ```path('step2')``` call.

Comment: @mTorres ,I checked that, the path is correct and the route exist but still have the problem of requested url not found

Comment: Can you post the code (the HTML form)? Also, where you define your / route? In the yaml file or in the PHP file?

Comment: hi again, i still have the same issue but i kind serrounded it, there is a conflict between the htaccess and the route.yml .